# Is there any way to let main thread do its own task and not waiting for its sub thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix

I'm doing a project on Linux recently. I want my main thread to create subthreads and then go back to its own work. And when a subthread terminates, the main thread join the subthread. It's something like calling wait_pid() in SIG_CHLD handler when using process.

Is there any way to implement this in thread?

Comment: Set the threads to detached so you don't have to join them?

Comment: Maybe you could send a signal (like SIGUSR1) from the thread when it's finishing? You'd have to mask the signal in all threads other than main.

Comment: Also if you set the threads to detached as suggested by Shawn, instead of using signals you could use a mutex and a condition variable to achieve the same effect, i.e. get notification when the task is completed.

Comment: Thank you all. I decide to detach the thread and use condition variable.